# Heroku Nginx HTTP 413 entity too large

Tags: heroku, nginx, laravel-5

I'm getting **error 413** when uploading a 4MB file. I have already created a `.user.ini` file on the `public/` folder. to allow up to 10 MB files

So I used `client_max_body_size` like this on my `nginx.conf`, **but I still get 413.**

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

That configuration is because I'm using `Laravel 5`.

This is my `Procfile`

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a bit late, but in order to fix this, move your `client_max_body_size 10M;` outside of the location section. Like this:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/beta/conf/nginx/heroku.conf.php#L35 for reference on how heroku includes this file.

Comment: where do you add those settings ?

Comment: wherever you are defining your config. if your procfile looked like `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/` then it would be nginx.conf